# How to set start date and end date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How to set Start Date and End Date using jQuery Mobile?

For example, I selected one date (i.e start date) `24-5-2011` (May 24th,2011) then end date will be in less than or equal to 100 days from the start date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var start = new Date('5/24/2011');
var daysTillEnd = 100;
var isBetween = isBetween(start, daysTillEnd);

function isBetween(start,days){
    var startTS = start.getTime();
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    var endTS = startTS + days*24*60*60*1000;
    return now >= startTS && now <= endTS;    
}
```

Comment: Err...does this answer the question..?